# Could we use Web Farm Framework 2.2 to create a server farm on windows server 2012?

Tags: web-farm, web-farm-framework

We want our application to run on web server farm.Is it possible to create web server farm  using web farm framework 2.2 on windows server 2012?We would be grateful if given detail setup procedure if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Currently does not support windows 2012

http://forums.iis.net/post/2032127.aspx